# What are the weapons used by Indra other than Vajra

Tags: indra, weapon

This question is related to [Rainbow question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12311/is-indradhanusha-really-bow-of-indra) in which I ask about the validity of the word Indra-Dhanusha in Hindu Mythology.

I want to know what are the other weapons Indra has since he is DevaRaja king of Gods he must have a great weaponry. I know that he uses Vajra the great weapon made out of Rishi Dadhichi's Spine , but just vajra is not enough since he is king.

Comment: Indra also has another weapon fashioned from Dadhichi's horse head; see my question and answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12006/36 That's different from the Vajra which was fashioned from Dadhichi's rib cage.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Indra had other weapons besides Vajra which was made from the rib cage of Sage Dadhichi. One of them is a bow named Vijaya. This is the bow used by Karna in the Kurukshetra. The first owner of this bow was Indra. Karna explains the history of this celestial bow to Duryodhana.

Below is an [excerpt](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08031.htm) from Karna Parva section 31.

> My bow, called Vijaya, is the foremost of all weapons (of its kind). Desirous of doing what was agreeable (to Indra), **it was made by Vishakarman (the celestial artificer) for Indra. With that bow, O king, Indra had vanquished the Daityas.** At its twang the Daityas beheld the ten points to be empty. That bow, respected by all, Sakra gave to Bhrigu's son (Rama). That celestial and foremost of bows Bhrigu's son gave to me. With that bow I will contend in battle with the mighty-armed Arjuna, that foremost of victorious warriors, like Indra fighting with the assembled Daityas. That formidable bow, the gift of Rama, is superior to Gandiva. It was with that bow that the Earth was subjugated thrice seven times (by Bhrigu's son).

It is possible that there are many bows made for Indra by Vishvakarma besides this bow Vijaya. In the [section 82](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08082.htm) of Karna Parva it is mentioned as below.

> Shooting his shafts with that **large and extended bow of his that resembled the bow of Sakra himself**, the son of Adhiratha looked resplendent like the sun, with his multitude of blazing rays, within his corona.

So we can assume that there are many other bows owned by Indra which resemble the Vijaya bow.

Indra also has an excellent golden chariot. Indra sends this chariot for Rama to fight Ravana in the battle field.

> रथेन मम भूमिष्ठं शीघ्रं याहि रघूत्तमम् || ६-१०२-७
>   आयूय भूतलं यातः कुरु देवहितं महत् |
>
> rathena mama bhūmiṣṭhaṃ śīghraṃ yāhi raghūttamam || 6-102-7
>   āyūya bhūtalaṃ yātaḥ kuru devahitaṃ mahat |
>
> "Go quickly with my chariot to Rama, who is standing on the earth. After reaching the earth, invite him to take his seat in the chariot and carry out a great service to the gods."

[Here](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga102/yuddha_102_frame.htm) is the description of the same chariot:

> Then came the glorious and excellent chariot of Indra, having variegated body decked in gold, which was fitted with hundreds of tiny bells, with its pole of cat's eye gems shone like the morning sun, yoked to excellent green horses, having golden chaplets on their heads, having white whisks, covered with nets of gold, shining like the sun and bearing a flag-staff raised on a golden bamboo. Ascending the chariot, as enjoined by Indra and descending from paradise, Matali approached Rama.

Indra has a noose which is mentioned in the Rig  Veda and the Atharvana Veda.

In Rig Veda Mandala 7 [Hymn 104](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07104.htm),

> 13 Never doth Soma aid and guide the wicked or him who falsely claims the Warrior's title. He slays the fiend and him who speaks untruly: both lie entangled in the **noose of Indra**.

In Atharvana Veda Kanda 8 Sukta 4 mantra 24 which is a prayer against enemies.

> 24 Whatever, etc. Let him not be freed from the **noose of Indra**-
>     Agni, etc.

He also wields a net named indrajāla with which he has slain millions of dasyus.

It is mentioned several times in the [Atharvana Veda Kanda 8, Sukta 8](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av08008.htm).

> 7 Great is thy net, brave Indra, thine the mighty match for a
>      thousand, Lord of Hundred Powers!
>     Holding them, with his host, therewith hath Indra slaughtered
>     Dasyus a hundred, thousand, myriad, hundred millions.
>
> 8 This world so mighty was the net of Sakra, of the Mighty One:
>     With this, the net of Indra, I envelop all those men with gloom.

Comment: But how can we conclude, that Vajra and bows are the only weapons owned/weilded by indra.

Comment: I didn't conclude that these are the only weapons. I will add some more weapons if found. @Yogi

Answer (score 2):

Lord Indra has many weapons rather than just a Vajra. Lord Indra also has:

Indra Kaakam - A sword which has a  crescent - shaped tip

A quiver of  inexhaustible arrows

Vijaya Dhanush

The Deva mace

The Deva Chakra

A personal spear

The Indra Axe

More than a 100000000 astras

Maya Illusions

A Goad

A Special Trident

A lotus

A conch which is golden

The deva noose

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
Lord Indra has immortality, because of Amirta, A heavenly pot of nectar. Lord Indra's mount is a white elephant named Iravat. Lord Indra has a golden chariot that surpasses many people.

Comment: Cite sources refrences in your answer

Comment: http://hindumythologyforgennext.blogspot.com.au/search/label/Stories%20of%20Arjuna

Answer (score -1):

Goad is a weapon he has also...like he is sometimes shown with lotus also..& sometimes with akshamala & kalash too...like these things r shown in his 4 hands image...source-shodhganga's article:)
http://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/74856/15/15_chapter%208.pdf

Comment: it was an article of dikpal...i will give u its link soon:)

Comment: i gave the link of where i found it out...is it valid?