# Do the Four Elements shown in Avatar Airbender series have any basis in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, gods, agni, panchabhoota, vayu

Do the four elements (fire, water, earth and air) shown in the [Avatar (The Last Airbender)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar:_The_Last_Airbender) series have any basis in Hinduism?

Is this just a fun way to represent in Hinduism or are there verses in Hindu scriptures to back it up?

[image]

Comment: The system of five elements called "PanchaMahbhutas" is there in Hinduism & not just of four .1) Earth (Bhumi) , Jal(Water) ,Fire (Agani) , Wind (Maruta ,Vayu) Space ( Vyoma) . What's the funny part in this?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar its called wind not air and it has 2 names maruta and vayu.

Comment: Do they actually say so in the movie series (or in the script?) that they are related to Hinduism? If yes, your question is a valid one. If not, then you are just speculating, which is not allowed here. If latter, [Movies.SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask this question. If former, you need to write something in your question to link the movie to Hinduism. E.g., notes from script or the director saying he was inspired by Hinduism.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar its called avatar is that not enough?  There are also reincarnations.  Hinduism - notably, the seven chakras are also in the tv show.

Comment: @William - Mostly this is universal concept.So irrespective of what "Avatar" or any other fantasy movie say , it's found in majority of religion's including Hinduism - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_element

Comment: See [What is the meaning of five elements(Pancha Bhootas) in Hinduism?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15492/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer I'm okay with marking it as a duplicate.  I assumed there were only four not five.

Comment: @William Actually the five subtle (not gross) elements are Air, water, fire, earth and ether. They are not normal air or water or fire or earth or space we see. They are subtle elements.

Comment: @William I think it showed four because these four are gross product which are formed from subtle (air water fire earth)... while space doesn't have gross matter..