# What are the eleven senses of Lord Brahma

Tags: bhagavata-purana, brahma

As per common knowledge, humans have **five** senses: **Vision, Hearing, Touch, Smell, Taste.**

From the [following](https://innerschool.org/spb/sb/10/13/en1) excerpt [Srimad Bhagavatham](https://innerschool.org/spb/sb/en1), we come to know that Lord Brahma has eleven senses. Are the above five senses include in these eleven?

> SB 10.13.56: Then, by the power of the effulgence of those
>   vishnu-murtis, Lord Brahma, his eleven senses jolted by astonishment
>   and stunned by transcendental bliss, became silent, just like a
>   child's clay doll in the presence of the village deity.

List out the eleven senses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite easy actually. We know that we have the 5 Jyanendriyas (senses related to knowledge/perception) + the 5 Karmendriyas (senses related to action). Plus we have the mind (or Manas) as the 11th Indriya (sense/sensory organ).

See the following verses from the Manu Smriti:

> 2.89. **Those eleven organs** which former sages have named, I will properly (and) precisely enumerate in due order,
>
> **2.90. (Viz.) the ear, the skin, the eyes, the tongue, and the nose as the fifth, the anus, the organ of generation, hands and feet, and the
>   (organ of) speech, named as the tenth.**
>
> 2.91. Five of them, the ear and the rest according to their order, they call organs of sense, and five of them, the anus and the rest,
>   organs of action.
>
> 2.92. **Know that the internal organ (manas) is the eleventh**, which by its quality belongs to both (sets); when that has been subdued, both
>   those sets of five have been conquered.

So, we have:

- 5 Jyanendriyas

Ear, skin, eyes, tongue and nose.

- 5 Karmendriyas

Anus, genital, hands, feet and speech.

And, the 11th Indriya is the mind or Manas.