# What is the meaning of organ of action?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, indriyas

[Source](http://www.santosha.com/gita-chapter3.html)  verse  7

> yas tvindriyāṇi manasā niyamyārabhate ’rjuna
> karmendriyaiḥ karma-yogam asaktaḥ sa viśhiṣhyate
>
> The one who controls the senses by the mind and intellect, and engages
> the **organs of action** to Nishkaama Karma-yoga, is superior, O
> Arjuna.

What is the meaning of organ of action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Organs of action are called karmendriyas in the scriptures. karmendriyas are indriyas(organs) that do karma (action). They are generally five in number: mouth, hands, legs, reproductory organ, and excretory organs.

I am quoting a verse from Srimad Baghavatham that contains the relevant information

> The ten senses are the organs of [perception of] hearing, touching,
> seeing, tasting and smelling, **with the [organs of action known as
> the] mouth, the hands, the legs, the genitals and the organs of
> excretion as the tenth**.
>
> [[13, 26, 3, Srimad Baghavatham ]](https://bhagavata.org/canto3/chapter26.html#Text_13)

You can observe that mouth is used for speaking, legs are used for moving, hands are used for various tasks, etc.,

You can read [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29572/661) for more general information regarding indriyas.